# How to add a order to Transactions and billing agrrements?

Tags: magento-1.8, billing-agreements

I’m new to Magento. I know the little bit of definition about transactions and billing agreements modules under sales module.

Transactions: sometimes customer calls to the site admin and order some item at that time we can use to transaction details.

Billing agreements: billing agreement use when customer purchase item EMI based at that we can use billing agreement for customer.

But when I came to Transactions and Billing Agreements module only Reset Filter and Search options is there.

Where I can set the above methods (transactions & Billing Agreements) to product.
And how can I implement that functionality?
Can you give me brief information?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Billing Agreements currently only work via PayPal (natively - there are extensions out there which provide expanded functionality). [There is ample documentation on the Magento KB](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-billing-agreements-through-paypal); setup is as follows:

> ## Enabling and Configuring Billing Agreements
>
> Prior to creating and using billing agreements in Magento Enterprise Edition 1.9, the store administrator needs to first enable and configure billing agreements in the system:
>
> 1. In the Magento Admin Panel, choose System > Configuration. Select the PayPal tab on the left.
> 2. In the PayPal Billing Agreement Settings panel, you can set the following values:
>
>    - To add billing agreements as a payment option in the Payment Information section of the shopping cart Checkout page, set the Enabled field to Yes. During the checkout process, the billing agreement payment option will become visible after the customer creates any billing agreements in her or his customer account.
>    - In the Title field, enter the name of the billing agreement payment option that will be available to customers on the Billing Agreements tab of the customer account and in the Payment Information section of the shopping cart Checkout page.
>    - If there are a number of payment methods to be used in the shopping cart, in the Sort Order field determine the order the billing agreement option will be displayed in the Payment Information section of the shopping cart Checkout page in the frontend.
>    - In the Payment Action field, choose the way payments will be authorized in the PayPal payment system and the entities that will be created in the backend as a result of the payment procedure. The following options are available:
>    - - Authorization - payments are only authorized at the side of the PayPal system and only an order is created in the backend of your store. The store administrator needs to log on to the merchant account on the PayPal site and capture the transaction.
>    - - Sale- a payment is authorized and captured at PayPal's side and as a result an order and an invoice are created in the backend of your store.
>    - Choose customers of which countries can use this method of payment in the Payment Applicable From field.
>    - In the Debug Mode field, specify whether data messages about all sent to the payment system and received from it information will be written into the system log file. Note that credit card related information is NOT written to the log file in order to prevent credit card fraud.
>    - In the Transfer Cart Line Items field, choose whether shopping cart lines, i.e. items and their prices, are transferred separately line by line or they are transferred as one whole with their price total value.
>    - The customer is able to create billing agreements from the customer account if the Allow in Billing Agreements Wizard option is enabled in the configuration.
>
> Click the [Save Config] button.